# Generate unsigned release APK with Android Studio

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, apk, android-studio

I am trying to generate an unsigned release APK using Android Studio.

My app will not be signed and not distributed on the Store.

In Android studio, I go to Build Variants and I select my project + Build Variant = Release.

I run the release, Android studio generates the file my_project-release-unsigned.apk

Nice! But, when I try to install or deploy the APK, I got the error:

```
Installation failed since the APK was either not signed, or signed incorrectly.
```

I dont understand why I got this error since the APK has been explicitly generated unsigned!

Well, if you could tell me how I can setup gradle to generate my APK unsigned....

I am pretty lost!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [Signing Your Application](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html):

> All applications **must** be signed. The system will not install an application on an emulator or a device if it is not signed.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking it wasnt mandatory to sign the APK. Thanks for the update! I just created a self signed cert using the Android Studio Wizard ... too easy!